# Is internal direct sum associative and commutative?

Tags: modules, direct-sum

For modules we can say "External direct sum is associative and commutative up to isomorphism." If we are using internal direct sum I think we can say it is associative and commutative (They are equal not only isomorphic). Am I right? I tried to prove and didn't see any problem.
I mean I can say;

Let A,B,C are submodules of M then
$ M=A \oplus B \Rightarrow M=B \oplus A $

and

$ M=(A\oplus B)\oplus C \Rightarrow M=A \oplus(B\oplus C) $

Right?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much.